# Using mac book built in camera with iOS simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I am new to iOS application development and I am using XCode4. I am trying to develop an application which uses the camera. For testing is there a way to integrate the built in camera of mac book to iOS simulator..?

Thanks.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You cannot use mac book's camera. For camera, you need to test it on a device.

From Apple documentation,

> The following hardware is not supported in Simulator:
>
> - Ambient light sensor
> - Audio input, except for using Siri by choosing Hardware > Siri.
> - Barometer
> - Bluetooth
> - Camera
> - Motion support (accelerometer and gyroscope)
> - Proximity sensor

Ref: 
[Apple documentation reference](https://help.apple.com/simulator/mac/current/#/devb0244142d)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Any online links confirming this since I have to share this with my manager.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and reference, wish this wasn't the case :(

Comment: This post is old. Is this really still true?

Comment: @KatedralPillon Yes, it is still true. Go to the provided link and check the content under title "Hardware Limitations".

Comment: if the feature are available....someone could upload some dummy github project just to use your macbook camera :p

Comment: This is what a shame

Answer (score 5):

You can now use a USB web camera on a M1 chip Mac mini or the native camera on a M1 chip MacBookPro running Big Sur and Xcode 13.1 with the simulator for iPad.xib iOS applications that need a camera! Choose the device tab "My Mac (designed for iPad)"

Comment: Is it working with virtual camera?