# Is there Camera Device Simulation in iOS Simulators?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Android emulators can simulate Camera device (see screenshot)
For example I can test how my video recording module works:

[image: Android Emulator, camera simulation example]

What about iOS-Simulators? When I try to run my app which uses camera I get the next error

```
Thread 5: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

at line

```
let videoDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: defaultVideoDevice!)
```

so no simulated devices are available for iOS-Simulators?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using mac book built in camera with iOS simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805630/using-mac-book-built-in-camera-with-ios-simulator)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to [Apple documentation](https://help.apple.com/simulator/mac/current/#/devb0244142d), using camera with Simulator is not supported:

> The following hardware is not supported in Simulator:
>
> - Ambient light sensor
> - Audio input, except for using Siri by choosing Hardware > Siri.
> - Barometer
> - Bluetooth
> - Camera
> - Motion support (accelerometer and gyroscope)
> - Proximity sensor

Comment: I see.. at least they allow simulate GPS

Comment: @user155, Yes, GPS simulation is supported

Comment: My hatred for Apple grows every day because of these limitations.

Comment: Because Apple is greedy, and forces people to buy devices even for a basic thing like camera simulation, which Android emulators have since few years now..

Answer (score 2):

There is one known workaround which could be useful sometimes: https://github.com/YuigaWada/iCimulator

But it does not work with 3-rd party libs like WebRTC though...